# If you are applying for a software engineering internship, will an employer look at your Github account?

Tags: software-industry, internship, employer

Will employers look at the "Public Activity" section of your Github account? I was messing around with the command line and made a repo with the name of a bad word, and I realize that employers might view me as immature for calling a test repo this name. I didn't save the repo or anything, I just very quickly made it once, and it was at the bottom of my public activity feed.

Will employers look at my Github activity this deeply?

Comment: I have a friend, whose very first script of _every_ project he does (commercial, private or whatever) is called "hovno" or "hovínečko" (both being plebeian words for the excrements). I doubt it has ever caused him any problems ... :D

Comment: I _think_ that many programmers are like that, so employers ignore it. However, I really can't assure you about it. (that's why I posted a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Would definitely appreciation other peoples' inputs as well though!

Comment: It depends on the workplace culture. Would you like to work in a culture that doesn't respect _real_ work (i.e. examples on github)  and instead focuses on things like swearing? If this is the reason you were rejected you did yourself a favour.

Comment: They may not happen to notice on github, but I bet they noticed that you just announced it on workplace SE :)

Comment: How would they know who I am Brandon?

Comment: Wait, you mean user3139679 isn't your real name?!

Comment: @ElectricLlama, so would it be fine with your company if OP used the same term when in a meeting with clients?  When the company hires you, they are hiring your skills and your behavior.  Not all employers will care, but I don't think those that care are bad places to work by definition.

Comment: [This Google talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SARbwvhupQ) is 55 minutes long and worth every single one. It basically says don't be scared of doing stupid stuff that stay on record forever (and these are google guys so forever really means *forever*). Admittedly they mean doing stupid stuff with *code* but I wouldn't lose any sleep over some repo name that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @cdkMoose - no it would be unacceptable to use that language in a meeting with clients. I don't see the correlation between a github comment and a client meeting though.

Comment: You can make this particular repo private or maybe use a different github account for such kind of projects

Comment: @ElectricLlama, Given that I know nothing about the applicant before this, when I see this behavior in a "public" setting, it at least plants a questioning seed in my mind about a behavior/professionalism.  The fact that OP has asked the question shows that I am not the only one who has had the same thought.  As an manager, I really don't care what you do in the privacy of your on home/life as long as it is legal.  But one could hardly argue that "my public activity feed" qualifies as private.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the employer. I've had some flat out ask me in the initial contact email if I had a github account and what was it and I've had others who weren't even aware that I knew how to use GIT version control until I got the gig. I've found that generally speaking newer companies and/or ones with younger company cultures are more likely to look at it than larger companies or ones with more formal cultures. The ones that do typically tend to glance through them and see what technologies you use but if you're really concerned it might be best to simply change the name of the repo.

Comment: Yeah I did. Just worried that they've already seen it at this point. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Having a github or similar with publicly available code is a good way to show employers your skill and something you should add to your resume. 
Having a project named something offensive is a bad idea, but if it's just test code, I don't think it will turn away too many employers.

Now you deleted the project, so I don't think it will make any difference at all.

See this as a good learning experience to always use proper variable names and textmessages, even while playing around, testing and debugging.
I've personally seen a log with the exception message "This should never happen" in a production system. And there are [stories of worse mistakes](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/We-Burned-the-Poop.aspx).

Comment: Firefox very often displays a dialog with "Should not see me" :) So I don't think it's that big of an issue - perhaps a bit funny to see.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your real question is whether they will be offended by your repo name, not just whether or not they will look at github.

I may be old school, but I am a hiring manager, so I will share my thoughts on your question.  When I am interviewing candidates, I am looking at the entire candidate, not just the technical skills.  Over the years, I have worked with programmers who had better than average to excellent skills, that I would never have hired because of personality/behavior issues.  As a manager, I am building a team, and those traits can be critical to the success of the whole team, regardless of your skill level.

I'm not saying I wouldn't hire you because of the repo name, but you would likely have raised some negative questions in my mind, before I have even met you for the interview.  The fact that you chose to use a term that would not be acceptable in a business conversation, to name a publicly view-able repo, would make me wonder what else you might do along that line.  If I hire you, there will be times that you represent me as an extension of the team, and I need to know that you will represent the team appropriately.